continues speech recognition failed with SpeechRecognizer.ErrorServerDisconnected
using https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiSpeechToTextSample library for performing continuous speech recognition on Android 14. After long period of successful work - recognition method speechRecognizer.StartListening failed with error SpeechRecognizer.ErrorServerDisconnected
the application is responsive and not crashed.
Below is repeated code :
var taskResult = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener
{

    Error = ex => {
        // Here is place of  SpeechRecognizer.ErrorServerDisconnected
        taskResult.TrySetException(new Exception("Failure in speech engine - " + ex));
        },
    PartialResults = sentence =>
    {
        recognitionResult?.Report(sentence);
    },
    Results = sentence => taskResult.TrySetResult(sentence)
};


if (speechRecognizer is null)
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(Android.App.Application.Context);

if (speechRecognizer is null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Speech recognizer is not available");
}


speechRecognizer.Cancel();
speechRecognizer.SetRecognitionListener(listener);
speechRecognizer.StartListening(CreateSpeechIntent(culture));


await using (cancellationToken.Register(() =>
{
    StopRecording();
    taskResult.TrySetCanceled();

}))
{

    int timeout = 10000;

    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskResult.Task, Task.Delay(timeout));
   
    if (completedTask == taskResult.Task)
    {
        // task completed within timeout
        var resultTask = await taskResult.Task;
        return resultTask;

    }
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("The Recognition operation has timed out.");


    }
}

When I close application and run it again from  foreground service I receive same error - only after complete service restart, Speech recognition recovered.

Which platform did you use and when this issue will happen after you run the project?

Android 14. Can not say exactly - all time is different.

The availability of an Internet connection may be necessary depending on the chosen recognition language. On Windows, the speech recognition system automatically adjusts between online and offline modes based on Internet accessibility. You can check if you have the good internet connection.

@GuangyuBai-MSFT I think I found cause -
2024-09-08 04:18:13.199  1382-1382  ActivityManager         system_server                        W  bindService exceeded max service connection number per process, callerApp:system intent:Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.apps.speech.tts.googletts.service.GoogleTTSRecognitionService }
After stop Speech Recognition and Synthesis from Google and restart my application it start to work again
Do you know what is  max service connection number per process ? Why it happen? What I am doing wrong?
